# Drop connections with a mismatching client certificate CN in nginx TCP reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, tcp

I'm using nginx to add TLS functionality on top of an existing TCP server (Redis) by proxying it like so (please read on before saying "Redis has builtin TLS support"):

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 6379 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/tls.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/tls.key;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    proxy_pass redis:679;
  }
}
```

However, this will accept *all* client certificates that have been signed by the specified CA. I'd like to only accept client certificates with a specific CN: `cn=api`. When proxying HTTP I can use an `if` statement like this

```
if ($ssl_client_s_dn != "CN=api") {
  return 403;
}
```

However, it seems that `if` statements like that are not allowed in stream servers. As a workaround I've used a `map` statement to route requests that don't match the CN to a nonexistent upstream like this:

```
stream {
  upstream redis_backend {
    server redis:6379;
  }

  map $ssl_client_s_dn $backend_svr {
    "CN=api" redis_backend;
    default null;
  }

  server {
    ...

    proxy_pass $backend_svr;
  }
}
```

However, I can't help but feel that there must be a better way to reject the connection for mismatching client certificates.